# Jquery: DatePicker: start/end date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have looked around before posting my question

following what i am looking in my datepicker (start date and end date):

1) **Start date:** can be any date, (user can select start date current (now) to any future date.

2) **Start date:**  user can select start date as back as 6 months.
 *example: if today is 04/22/2010 then i can go back up to 11/22/2009* but not more than 6 moths.

3) **Start date** if the user select the start date (current of future, not past)  less then 10 days then i would like to alert message saying "need at least 10 days"

4) **End date:** should be current date to future dates alll previous dates are disabled.

5) **Start date / End date: **  should not be greater than one year.

Thanks so much.

PS: not sure if i am asking too much here :)

Comment: are you trying to modify you existing datePicker? or find a substitute? Is it one datepicker or two for start & end dates?

Comment: i was using a thirdparty control and i am thinking of implementing jquery datepicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered a similar question for a friend. He needed a cascading date similar, but I think you can see how to solve the issue if you look at my markup.

HTML

```
  <form target="_self" action="ClearForm.aspx">
```

Clear Form

- Start Date:
- End Date:
- Clear

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#endDate').datepicker({ showOn: 'button',
      buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png',
      buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect: function () { },
      onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); }
    });


  $('#startDate').datepicker({ showOn: 'button',
      buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png',
      buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect:
        function (dateText, inst) {
          $('#endDate').datepicker("option", 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
        }
      ,
      onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); }
    });


});
```

Comment: @Chris, i have removed dateText and it works what i want which means i have done with #4

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="tbStartDate" value="" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" id="tbEndDate" value="" disabled="disabled" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbStartDate").datepicker({        
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: '/Content/Calendar.png',
            buttonText: 'Click here (date)',
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                 var $endDate = $('#tbStartDate').datepicker('getDate');
                 $endDate.setDate($endDate.getDate() + 1);
                 $('#tbEndDate').datepicker('setDate', $endDate).datepicker("option", 'minDate', $endDate);
            },
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                //$("#StartDate").val($("#tbStartDate").val());
            }
        });

        $("#tbEndDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: '/Content/Calendar.png',
            buttonText: 'Click here (date)',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                //$("#EndDate").val($("#tbEndDate").val());
            }
        });

            var $endDate = $('#tbStartDate').datepicker('getDate');
            $endDate.setDate($endDate.getDate() + 1);
            $('#tbEndDate').datepicker('setDate', $endDate).datepicker("option", 'minDate', $endDate);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write a default configuration for the datepicker using a class so that it works with more than one with less duplicates.

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
    // Check if _until exists and auto set mindate
    if(inst.id.contains("_from")){
        $("#"+inst.id.replace("_from", "_until")).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
    }
}
```

This works assuming your form IDs are consistent. E.g I use date_until and date_from