# jQuery timepicker addon to restrict end_time field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using jQuery timepicker addon (https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) on 2 files with #start_time and #end_time ids. I want #end_time must be larger or start from the time of #start_time. I tried below code but i am not good in jQuery.

```
$(function() {
$('#start_time').timepicker({ 
    onClose: function(timeText, inst) {
        if ($('#end_time').val() != '') {
            var testStartTime = $('#start_time').timepicker('getTime');
            var testEndTime = $('#end_time').timepicker('getTime');
            if (testStartTime > testEndTime)
                $('#end_time').timepicker('setTime', testStartTime);
        }
        else {
            $('#end_time').val(timeText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedTime){
        $('#end_time').timepicker('option', 'minTime', $('#start_time').timepicker('getTime') );
    }
});
$('#end_time').timepicker({ 
    onClose: function(timeText, inst) {
        if ($('#start_time').val() != '') {
            var testStartTime = $('#start_time').timepicker('getTime');
            var testEndTime = $('#end_time').timepicker('getTime');
            if (testStartTime > testEndTime)
                $('#start_time').timepicker('setTime', testEndTime);
        }
        else {
            $('#start_time').val(timeText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedTime){
        $('#start_time').timepicker('option', 'maxTime', $('#end_time').timepicker('getTime') );
    }
});
});
```

I have two time inputs start_time and end_time.

Comment: Can you specify a URL for the timepicker you are using?  I think there is more than one out there.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly but are you trying to compare the start time and end time and making sure that end time is greater than start time?

Answer (score 3):

```
        var startDateTextBox = $('#dialog_missionAdd input[name=scheduleStarttime]');
        var endDateTextBox = $('#dialog_missionAdd input[name=scheduleEndtime]');

        startDateTextBox.timepicker({ 
            defaultValue: "00:00",
            timeFormat: "HH:mm",
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                if (endDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                    var testStartTime = startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
                    var testEndTime = endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
                    if (testStartTime > testEndTime) {
                        endDateTextBox.timepicker('setDate', testStartTime); }
                }
                else {
                    endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
                }
            },
            onSelect: function (selectedDateTime) {
                endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate') );
            }
        });

        endDateTextBox.timepicker({ 
            defaultValue: "00:00",
            timeFormat: "HH:mm", 
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                    var testStartTime = startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
                    var testEndTime = endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
                    if (testStartTime > testEndTime) {
                        startDateTextBox.timepicker('setDate', testEndTime); }
                }
                else {
                    startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
                }
            },
            onSelect: function (selectedDateTime) {
                startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate') );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this **Working Demo** please: http://jsfiddle.net/fMnw8/

How it works:

- It will not allow user to select `end_time` until you will choose `start_time`
- Then, it checked the `AM` & `PM` matching and further condition.

This will give you enough hint to play around.

Hope it will fit your cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(function() {
    $('#start_time').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
        ampm: true,
        hour: 10,
        onSelect: function(selectedTime) {
            sHours = parseInt(selectedTime.substring(0, 2));
            sMins = parseInt(selectedTime.substring(3, 6));
            sAmpm = selectedTime.substring(6, 8);

            if (sAmpm == 'PM') {
                sHours = sHours + 12;
            }

            $('#end_time').remove();
            start_val = $('#start_time').val();
            $('<input id="end_time" value="' + start_val + '"/>').timepicker({
                timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
                hourMin: sHours,
                sMinutes: sMins,
                ampm: true,
                hour: 10,
                onSelect: function(selectedTime) {
                    eHours = parseInt(selectedTime.substring(0, 2));
                    eMins = parseInt(selectedTime.substring(3, 6));
                    eAmpm = selectedTime.substring(6, 8);

                    if (eAmpm == sAmpm) {
                        if (sHours > eHours || sMins > eMins) {
                            alert('Sorry -Time is greater then start time');
                            $('#end_time').val("");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).insertAfter('#start_time');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: @Saleem heh `:)` okies, have you included JQ sources and if you can let me know what is not working then it will be cool `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I have modified few thing and its working now. Here is the code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#start_time').timepicker({ 
    timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
    ampm: true,
    hourMin: 8,
    hourMax: 18,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        if ($('#end_time').val() != '') {
            var testStartTime = $('#start_time').datetimepicker('getDate');
            var testEndTime = $('#end_time').datetimepicker('getDate');
            if (testStartTime > testEndTime) {
                $('#end_time').timepicker('setDate', testStartTime); }
        }
        else {
            $('#end_time').val(dateText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
        if (testStartTime > testEndTime) {
        $('#end_time').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#start_time').datetimepicker('getDate') );
        }
    }
});

$('#end_time').timepicker({ 
    timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
    ampm: true,
    hourMin: 8,
    hourMax: 18,    
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        if ($('#start_time').val() != '') {
            var testStartTime = $('#start_time').datetimepicker('getDate');
            var testEndTime = $('#end_time').datetimepicker('getDate');
            if (testStartTime > testEndTime) {
                $('#start_time').timepicker('setDate', testEndTime); }
        }
        else {
            $('#start_time').val(dateText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
        if (testStartTime > testEndTime) {
        $('#start_time').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#end_time').datetimepicker('getDate') );
        }
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Takek a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2694937/243639 to get started.  Of particular interest is the line that contains `$('#endDate').datepicker("option", 'minDate', new Date(dateText));`.  You can use new date in your onSelect function for one timepicker to set the minDate (or maxDate) of the other.

The timepicker is an extension of the jQuery datepicker referred to in the other SO post, so the solution ought to apply to timepicker as well.

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer that worked for you best :-)